# How do I get TextChanged events from an editable ComboBox

Tags: wpf

I have an editable ComboBox:

```xml
<ComboBox IsEditable="true"/>
```

What is the event that is raised when the edited value is changed? I have tried TextInput but that is not the solution.

Comment: Try the TextChanged event and see if it works.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged" />
```

...should do it.  (Assuming you want something that will fire every time a change is made to the text, rather then when the user has finished entering the text. In which case you'd need another event - maybe a LostFocus event or something?)

Anyway, the reason why the above XAML works is that, when IsEditable is set to true, the ComboBox uses a TextBox for displaying and editing the text.  The TextBox's TextChanged event is a [bubbling event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) - meaning it will bubble up through the element tree so we can handle it on the ComboBox itself.

The only 'tricky' bit is that ComboBox doesn't expose a TextChanged event itself but you can still define a handler for it using an [attached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx) (hence the TextBoxBase.TextChanged syntax).

(It's probably worth noting for completeness, that if the ComboBox happened to contain more than one TextBox then the handler would be called whenever any of them had their text changed.)

Comment: Why would adding a style to the combobox's resources which targeted type of TextBox and had an event setter for TextChanged not accomplish the same thing?  This was my first thought till I found it didn't work. Your solution works, but was wondering why my alternative didn't.

Comment: @MikeG: Good question. I think that approach would work, but only if the TextBox doesn't get another style applied to it. I suspect that the ComboBox's control template sets a style on the TextBox which is overriding your style.

Comment: I haven't looked in Snoop to see if that is the case, but I bet you're correct with the assumption that the ComboBox is overriding the default TextBox style. I'd have to imagine that the TextChanged is used internally by the ComboBox for its functionality.  I think your solution is "more correct/complete" due to the fact that I believe it leverages attached properties in a manner that they were designed to be used.

Comment: When trying this I get `Failed to created a 'TextChanged' from the text 'ComboBox_TextChanged'` even if I replace `ComboBox` with the appropriate `x:Name` value.

Answer (score 24):

Based on the approach above I had a look into the (XAML) generated code.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Add the following code to initialization:

```
myComboBox.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.TextChangedEvent, 
                      new System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler(ComboBox_TextChanged));
```

This works fine for me, because I needed a reusable ComboBox (SQL-Server dropdown list) which encapsulates all behaviour.

Comment: I've found this works great for the TextChanged event in particular, but it does not work with the SelectionChanged event, likely due to the ambiguity between the ComboBox's SelectionChanged event and the TextBox's SelectionChanged event.

Is it possible to do something similar for that specific event?

Answer (score 3):

PreviewTextInput event gets triggered for every keyboard input in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

Add --->> `TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged"`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank the answer from IanR and Girish Reddyvari as it got me thinking.

I'm using Caliburn Micro and I'm trying to get the input of the Editable ComboBox while they are typing. Caliburn Micro didn't easily pick up the event

```
 TextBoxBase.TextChanged
```

as my background in xaml and interactivity isn't good enough! But it did pick up

```
  KeyUp
```

My code using Caliburn Micro is different but the following code should also work

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" KeyUp="ComboBox_TextChanged" />
```