# WPF TextBoxBase property missing (and others too)

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I could not resolve the issue, that the TextBoxBase property is missing from controls. If I make a TextBox, I can define the TextBoxbase property, but nowhere else. If I write `TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Window_TextChanged"` in the window element, then it is accepted, however intellisense does not provide it, furthermore, no call happens during runtime. ButtonBase, etc do no appear also.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

First the `TextBoxBase` is not a property of any WPF element, that's a class. Second `TextChanged` is an event that [occcurs when content changes in the text element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) - makes only sense for text elements like `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`.

Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes!
I am learning routed events in WPF. More precisely how does tunneling and bubbling work and trying to complete an exercise of it:
There is a textbox with TextChanged event. When it is changed a MessageBox appears. The exercise tells me if I add `TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Grid_TextChanged"` and `TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Window_TextChanged"` to the `Grid` and `Window` control, then they should handle the textchange event as well.

Comment: I see. Can you verify you haven't set `args.Handled` to `true` which stops bubbling. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914942/how-do-i-get-textchanged-events-from-an-editable-combobox for more and use WPF Spy Utility Snoop https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ which is very helpful.

Comment: Me silly. Yes, the handled = true was the problem! Furthermore, could you  tell me why the intellisense does not provide the `TextBoxBase`, etc class in XAML editor? For the `TextBox` itself it shows `TextBoxBase` but not for other controls.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know answer to that question.