# Editable ComboBox not working with TextChanged KeyEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have an `Editable` `ComboBox`, but only want to allow `Numbers` and `Backspace` when typing in it.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915144/6806643) how to add a `TextChange Event` to it with `TextBoxBase.TextChanged`.

When compiling, I get the error:

> No overload for 'cboVideo_TextChanged' matches delegate
>   'TextChangedEventHandler`

---

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboVideo" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Video_Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Video_SelectedItem}" 
          SelectionChanged="cboVideo_SelectionChanged"    

          IsEditable="{Binding Video_IsEditable, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Text="{Binding Video_Text}"
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cboVideo_TextChanged"

          IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 

          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="105" 
          Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
```

Was originally `RoutedEventArgs`, I changed it to `KeyEventArgs`.

```
// Only allow Numbers and Backspace
//
private void cboVideo_TextChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) && e.Key != Key.Back)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the error message says it all. You just need to read it. And then look at the documentation for `TextBoxBase.TextChanged` what the correct event delegate type (i.e. what method signature of a event handler method) would be for this event. "_Was originally RoutedEventArgs, I changed it to KeyEventArgs._" Sure, that's why the compiler complains. What would be the point of that anyway? The TextChanged event signals that the text has changed (the event name says as much), not signalling what key has been pressed. Maybe you want to look for some key-related events instead of TextChanged...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF - MVVM Textbox restrict to specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572460/wpf-mvvm-textbox-restrict-to-specific-characters)

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I was looking for `TextBoxBase.KeyDown` instead of `TextBoxBase.TextChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

It says:

> No overload for 'cboVideo_TextChanged' matches delegate 'TextChangedEventHandler`

---

That's compeletely normal because you are using the **wrong event arguments on wrong event handler**.

You **cannot handle** a `TextChanged` event with a `KeyEventArgs` event. You **have to use** `TextChangedEventArgs` with a `TextChanged` event handler.

After you change it to `TextChangedEventArgs`, you can get whatever is **changed** by property `TextChangedEventArgs.Changes`.

Then, just use a `switch()` or `if()` to do any **check**s. You can check **if the change is a number** then you can set `EventArgs.Handled` to `true` or `false`.

NOTE: You can also use `RoutedEventArgs` because `TextChangedEventArgs` **is based on it**. But I **recommend to use** `TextChangedEventArgs`.